# plotly won't disappear + (action Button) shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I have created a simple shiny app, based on mtcars dataset, with the ability to have a plotly option, by clicking on the checkboxInput, however when I unclick it, it won't disappear. How can I disappear/disable the plotly when I unclick the checkboxInput.

Also, I would like to add an actionbutton to the app, so only after clicking on the actionbutton the changes would appear.

Grateful for all help

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

dataset <- mtcars 

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  
  headerPanel("Mtcars"),
  sidebarPanel(sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size', min=10, max=nrow(dataset),
                           value=min(10, nrow(dataset)), step=5, round=0),
               selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset)),
               selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
               selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(dataset))),
               checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth'),
               selectInput('facet_row', 'Facet Row', c(None='.', names(dataset))),
               selectInput('facet_col', 'Facet Column', c(None='.', names(dataset))),
               hr(),
               checkboxInput("plotly1", "Reactive plot!",value = FALSE, width=140),
               actionButton("plot", "Plot!")
               
               
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot'),
    hr(),
    hr(),
    plotlyOutput("plot2")
    
    )
))
```

```
server<- shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  
  dataset <- reactive( { mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), input$sampleSize),] }) 
  
  
  gragh <- reactive({
    p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()
    if (input$color != 'None')
      p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)
    facets <- paste(input$facet_row, '~', input$facet_col)
    if (facets != '. ~ .')
      p <- p + facet_grid(facets)
    
    if (input$smooth)
      p <- p + geom_smooth()
    print(p)
    
    if (input$plotly1) {
      output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
        ggplotly(p)
        
      })
      
      
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
  gragh()
  })
  
  
  })


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a UI based approach via `conditionalPanel`. This avoids unnecessary re-rendering of the plotly chart in the server function and therefore is more responsive.

You can use `bindEvent` to trigger plotting with the `actionButton`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

dataset <- mtcars

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Mtcars"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput(
      'sampleSize',
      'Sample Size',
      min = 10,
      max = nrow(dataset),
      value = min(10, nrow(dataset)),
      step = 5,
      round = 0
    ),
    selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset)),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
    selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(dataset))),
    checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth'),
    selectInput('facet_row', 'Facet Row', c(None = '.', names(dataset))),
    selectInput('facet_col', 'Facet Column', c(None = '.', names(dataset))),
    hr(),
    checkboxInput(
      "plotly1",
      "Interactive plot!",
      value = FALSE,
      width = 140
    ),
    actionButton("plot", "Plot!")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot'),
    hr(),
    hr(),
    conditionalPanel("input.plotly1 === true", plotlyOutput("plot2"))
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
      mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), input$sampleSize), ]
    })
  gragh <- reactive({
    p <-
      ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) + geom_point()
    if (input$color != 'None')
      p <- p + aes_string(color = input$color)
    facets <- paste(input$facet_row, '~', input$facet_col)
    if (facets != '. ~ .')
      p <- p + facet_grid(facets)
    
    if (input$smooth)
      p <- p + geom_smooth()
    
    p
  }) |> bindEvent(input$plot)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    gragh()
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(gragh())
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the if-statement inside the `renderPlotly()`:

```r
output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
  if (input$plotly1) {
    ggplotly(p)
  }
})
```

Outputs persist after they are created once, rely on reactivity to change their result.